# React: Session Timeout Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on Session Timeout. Session will timeout in 5 min. Showing warning dialog 2 minutes(before the session timeout). Click Yes to extend the session and click No to close the dialog and session will be expired in two minutes.

Issue1: When I click No, it immediately expired the session and redirect me to the session expired page. How to do the session expired in 2 minutes.
Issue2: Timer showing on the warning dialog is not accurate. Sometime it expired 30 seconds before or 40 seconds before or 2 seconds before.

Please check my code, what I am doing wrong here.

```
    import React, { useEffect} from "react";
    import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
    export const SessionTimeoutWarningModal = ({ isOpen, onRequestClose }) => {
        const onLogOffCall = () => {
            // Implement your logout functionality here
            window.location.href = "/SessionExpired";
        }
           const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(120);
            useEffect(() => {
               const timer =
                    counter > 0 && setInterval(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
                return () => clearInterval(timer);
            }, [counter]);

           return (
                <div>
                    <Modal show={isOpen} className="modalPopup" contentLabel="Session Timeout">
                 <div className="modalPopupHeader"> Session Expiring! </div>
             <div className="modalPopupBody">
       Your session will expire in&nbsp;<span id="seconds">{counter}</span>&nbsp;seconds.<br />
                        Do you want to reset session timeout?
                    </div>
                        <div className="modalPopupFooter" align="center">
                            <button onClick={onRequestClose} className="Savebutton">Yes</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <button onClick={onLogOffCall} className="ButtonCancel">No</button>
                        </div>
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            );
        }

    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { SessionTimeoutWarningModal } from "./SessionTimeoutWarningModal";

    const timeout_ms = 5 * 60 * 1000;  //5 minutes
    export const SessionTimeout = () => {
        const [isWarningModalOpen, setWarningModalOpen] = useState(false);
      useEffect(() => {
            const createTimeout1 = () => setTimeout(() => {
                setWarningModalOpen(true);
            }, timeout_ms - 120 * 1000)  //Show Model Dialog 2 minutes before timeout  (at 3 minutes)
            const createTimeout2 = () => setTimeout(() => {
                // Implement a sign out function here
                window.location.href = "/AdminSessionExpired";
            }, 120*1000)
            const listener = () => {
                if (!isWarningModalOpen)
                {
               clearTimeout(timeout)
                    timeout = createTimeout1();
                }
            }
            // Initialization
            let timeout = isWarningModalOpen ? createTimeout2() : createTimeout1()
            // Cleanup
            return () => {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
        }, [isWarningModalOpen])
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    isWarningModalOpen && (
                    <SessionTimeoutWarningModal isOpen={isWarningModalOpen}
                           onRequestClose={() => setWarningModalOpen(false)}
                     />
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default SessionTimeout;

    import React from "react";
    import {Link, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
    export class SessionExpired extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                navigate: false
            };
            this.onSessionExpired = this.onSessionExpired.bind(this);
        }
        onSessionExpired(event)
        {
            localStorage.clear();
            window.sessionStorage.clear();
            this.setState({ navigate: true });
         }

        render() {
            const { navigate } = this.state;
            if (navigate) {
                return <Redirect to="/" push={true} />;
            }

            return (
                <div>
                    <div id="container">
                        <br />
                        <h5><b>Session Expired</b></h5>
                        <label>Your session has expired. Please <Link className="HomePageLink" onClick={this.onSessionExpired} >
                            return to home!</Link></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default SessionExpired;
```

Comment: another approach could be to start a poll few minutes before session expiry time, it will be off by max poll time.

Comment: click on No expire immediately. What needs to be done so that it will expire in 2 minutes

Comment: click on No expire immediately. What needs to be done so that it will expire in 2 minutes –

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience on the same subject:

1. I would recommend using this package: [react-idle-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-idle-timer).
   It is very reliable and is updated continuously.
   It also includes all the features you need - highly recommended!
2. I can see few things you can change:

   divide the timer into two parts: the first one will be until the modal is triggered and the second one from the moment the modal is opened until the timer is up.

   in case the user don't want to reset the modal you just close the modal but the timer will keep running.

   for the timers I personally used setTimeout() and in the callback I gave the timeout logic I wanted to happen. (for the first timer I triggered the modal, and for the second timer I navigate to login page and cleared the store etc.)

so basically I created a component that handles the modal and triggered the session timeout logic and also combined the idle timer package (even though I think it can be improved since they probably updated the library since then).

```
export type Props = {
    isOpenModal: boolean;
    toggleModal: any;
    onCloseModalCallback: any;
    timeLeftInSessionForTextMessage: number; //time for the modal in minutes
    extendingSessionCallback: any;
    className?: string;
    isUserIdle: boolean; // true when the modal is open
    timerId: number | undefined; // the timerId that I stored.
    setTimerId: any; // I store the timerId in parent component so that I could delete it whenever and wherever I want (in a saga, for example)
};
export const SessionTimeoutModal = () => {
useEffect(() => {
    if (isUserIdle) {
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            onCloseModalCallback();
        }, timeLeftInSessionForTextMessage * secondInMilliseconds * minuteInSeconds);
        setTimerId(timer);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
    }
}, [isUserIdle]);

//psuedocode
//<Modal>
    //OnClickExtendSessionButton: () => extendingSessionCallback()
    //OnClickCloseModalButton: () => onCloseModalCallback()
//</Modal>
}
```

In the parent component I used the 'react-idle-timer' timer component to combine everything together (and for using all its very useful props).

hope this was helpful

Comment: Thanks Rachel. Would you please helpme fix my code. everything is working fine. I just want fix in No click functionality. I am not sure how to close the dialog on No button click and session expire after 2 minutes

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you should handle your timer regardless to the fact the modal has been closed. for the prop 'onRequestClose' simply send 'setWarningModalOpen(false)' and don't clear the timer when the modal is closed. let it keep working until it is over. you need to make some changes in your useEffect function that the fact that the modal has been close will not affect the process of the timer. the only thing that would affect the modal timer is the button that reset it.